# How to make a composite key without making it a primary key in SQL Server ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to make a composite key without making it a primary key in SQL Server ?

I have two int columns in a table and I want to make them as composite key, but sadly I don't want them to set as primary key (Selecting both columns and select primary key in SSMS).

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you want to make them **unique** (in combination)?

Comment: Yes. they must be unique in combination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you mean by *making them composite key* ?

Do you want to make them **unique** (in combination)?

Just create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on them:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_YourTable_Col1_Col2
UNIQUE(Col1, Col2)
```

Or what else do you want to achieve by *making them composite key* ?